# Salesforce Console : how I can change Case record page to make highlights panel sticky

Tags: lightning-record-page

Anyone know what changes need to do for Salesforce Console to be sticky on the Case record page
[image: to display highlights panel at the top],

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? What part do you want to pin? Do you want to make it sticky (as in the question body) or just to move to the top (as in the title)? Sticky means that element will remain visible on the screen while scrolling the page.

Comment: It will better to mark in the image what need to be done..

Comment: The section with Follow and Edit buttons, want to make sticky

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The highlights panel the section with Follow and edit buttons